# broke some stuff in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

so I have this code that was a widget in a row called widget text.

```
a:15:{i:8;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:157:"<div align="center"><A href="http://mvprop.com/Deals-and-Specials"><IMG border=0 
      alt=Deals and Specials 
      src="dealsandspecials.gif"></A></div>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:14;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:153:"<div align="center"><A href="http://mvprop.com/24-Hour-Recording><IMG border=0 
      alt=24 Hour Recording 
      src="24hourrecording.gif"></A></div>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:16;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:147:"<div align="center"><A href="http://mvprop.com/We-Will-Buy-Now"><IMG border=0 
      alt=We Will Buy Now 
      src="wewillbuynow.gif"></A></div>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:20;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:123:"<div align="center"> <A href="http://mvprop.com/FAQS"><IMG border=0 
            alt=FAQS
      src="faqs.gif"></A></div>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:21;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:136:"<div align="center"><A href="http://mvprop.com/about-mvp"><IMG border=0 
            alt=About MVP 
      src="aboutus.gif"></A></div>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:23;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:163:"<div align="center"><A href="http://mvprop.com/Deals-and-Specials"><IMG border=0 
            alt=Deals and Specials 
      src="dealsandspecials.gif"></A></div>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:24;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:153:"<div align="center"><A href="http://mvprop.com/We-Will-Buy-Now"><IMG border=0 
            alt=We Will Buy Now 
      src="wewillbuynow.gif"></A></div>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:25;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:159:"<div align="center"><A href="http://mvprop.com/24-Hour-Recording><IMG border=0 
            alt=24 Hour Recording 
      src="24hourrecording.gif"></A></div>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:26;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:152:"<div align="center"><A href="http://mvprop.com/Sell-Your-Home"><IMG border=0 
            alt=Sell Your home 
      src="sellyourhome2.gif"></A></div>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:27;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:143:"<div align="center"> <A href="http://mvprop.com/WE-Will-Buy"><IMG border=0 
            alt=We Will Buy 
      src="wewillbuy.gif"></A></div>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:28;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:161:"<div align="center"> <A href="http://mvprop.com/We-Make-An-Offer"><IMG border=0 
            alt=We Will Make An Offer
      src="wemakeanoffer.gif"></A></div>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:33;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:170:" <br> <font size="2px face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> <br> Are you an Investor? <br> Are you tired of 
the stock market and looking for a better rate of return? </font>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:34;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:126:"<a href="../../investments/Questions.pdf"><img src="../../investments/top-ten.jpg" width="236" height="250" border="0"></a> 
";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:35;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:145:"  <div align="center"><A href="http://mvprop.com/investments"><IMG border=0 
            alt=Investors
      src="151-test-new2.jpg"></A></div>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}
```

apparently I deleted or added a space somewhere in this code.

Now It doesn't work. What do I do now? The change is somewhere in the second part.
If no way to fix it, is there a way to rebuild the widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that in your {wp-prefix}_options table?

I don't know if it can be fixed easily. Try using PHP's [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function to read those values

But, you can reset it by setting the field value to `a:0:{}` and start building your widgets again.

Comment: Okay thanks, but there are like no widgets installed on the site. This one was hard coded, and yes you are correct, it is the options table

Comment: Are you sure there were no widgets? This field is usually empty(you actually have `a:0:{}`) on a fresh wordpress install.

Answer (score 0):

I simply made another widget to solve my problem.